# QuickBooks POS Store Names

Tags: quickbooks, point-of-sale, intuit-partner-platform

I have 2 access questions within the Inuit QuickBooks POS SDK:

1. Can I access the Price Manager, and get sale dates for inventory items?
2. Can I access the preferences to get the current defined store names?

Thanks!

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about #1. I don't see SalesDate listed in the OSR.

Store names are in the CompanyQuery.